# I need to make my app always run in the background

Tags: flutter

I have a location app that app sends the location to API in the flutter, 
this app is working good, 
but I need to make my app always run in the background,
and it can stop only when the user makes it stopped...

is that possible in flutter???

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is,
probably the best package around is:
[background_locator](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator)

It's makes possible to run the location code as a background service.